# for loop adding same value together and make JSON format

Tags: python, json, list

```
test=[]
sites = sel.css(".info")
for site in sites:
    money = site.xpath("./h2[@class='money']/text()").extract()
    people = site.xpath("//p[@class='poeple']/text()").extract()
    test.append('{"money":'+str(money[0])+',"people":'+str(people[0])+'}')
```

My result `test` is:

```
['{"money":1,"people":23}', 
  '{"money":3,"people":21}', 
  '{"money":12,"people":82}', 
  '{"money":1,"people":54}' ]
```

I was stuck by two thing:

One is I print the type of `test`  is string,so is not like JSON format

Two is the `money` value with 1 is duplicate,so I need to add the people together ,
so the final format I want is:

```
[
{"money":1,"people":77},
{"money":3,"people":21},
{"money":12,"people":82},
]
```

How can I do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd collect money entries in a dict and add up the people as values, the output to json should be done using a json library indeed (I've not tested the code but it should give you an idea how you can approach the problem):

```
money_map = {}
sites = sel.css(".info")
for site in sites:
    money = site.xpath("./h2[@class='money']/text()").extract()[0]
    people = int(site.xpath("//p[@class='poeple']/text()").extract()[0])
    if money not in money_map:
        money_map[money] = 0

    money_map[money] += people

import json
output = [{'money': key, 'people': value} for key, value in money_map.items()]
json_output = json.dumps(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

basically this:

```
import json
foo = ['{"money":1,"people":23}',
  '{"money":3,"people":21}',
  '{"money":12,"people":82}',
  '{"money":1,"people":54}' ]


bar = []
for i in foo:
    j = json.loads(i) # string to json/dict
    # if j['money'] is not in bar:
    bar.append(j)
    # else:
    # find index of duplicate and add j['people']
```

Above is incomplete solution, you have to implement the 'duplicate check and add'